Can an Hall effect sensor fail in a way that causes drift in the final measurement?
I am investigating the different failure modes of an Hall-effect sensor. The failure modes such as short or open circuit are easy to diagnose but I am not sure if the Hall-effect sensor can have a drifting measurement over time and if it can be diagnosed without a redundance measurement.

Any component can drift. No, every component drifts! Is it ppm, %, factor of 2, orders of magnitude? Drift is the most difficult and time-consuming measurement to make reliably.

The first thing we need to know is the. Model# of the sensor. Some data you are seeing and the circuit it's in

Analog Hall Effect sensor are notoriously prone to drifting over time. They are also quite temperature sensitive. Specifically, an open-loop Hall Effect current sensor is likely to report there is current when there is none, or vice-versa. This is a major problem when calculating the State of Charge of a battery using Coulomb Counting.
Yes, there are ways to check the offset in an analog Hall Effect sensor, but they depends of the application. You haven't told us what the application is. Let me just describe a solution used in electric vehicles. When the vehicle is coasting or is parked, and the motor driver is not doing anything, the vehicle knows how much current the other loads are drawing from the battery. If the open-loop Hall Effect current sensor in the battery reports a different value, then the software can calculate the offset, and subtract it from future readings from the Hall Effect current sensor. If that offset is excessive, it issues a fault.

Can an Hall effect sensor fail in a way that causes drift in the final measurement?

Yes, it can. Which is why in the last sentence I said: " If that offset is excessive, it issues a fault."
But, again, the solution depends on what type of Hall Effect sensor you're using and what it's measuring.

Besides the drift in the Hall element itself, there is also the effect of nearby ferromagnetic materials having and varying their own magnetic field which could be constantly affecting the Hall sensor and appear as a drift over time. For example, a nearby steel structure under the influence of nearby magnetic fields of currents passing by and causing an increasing magnetization of the structure.
